Timestamping tag
Could be created special tag for timestamping ?
Cryptography Timestamping (a.k.a Trusted Timestamping), I think should deserve it's own tag. (IMHO "Cryptographic timestamping" is better name, because "trusted" might suggest PKI, which does not have to be used).
I vote for "timestamps" or "timestamping". 

Thanks for the proposal. PulpSpy created the tag by adding it to your question. Feel free to add the tag to other relevant questions, as the system will remove tags which are only on one question after some months.

It seems appropriate tag has been created. Thanks :).
